# Android layout_weight not avalible

Tags: android

```js
<i><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etCommands"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Type a Command"
        android:password="true" />

    <linearlayout
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
         >

        <Button
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:id="@+id/bResults"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:text="ToggleButton" />
    </linearlayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvResults"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="invalid" />

</LinearLayout></i>
```

**android:layout_weight="50"**
for both the button and toggle
the code of bold code gives the warning of "invalid layout param in a enter code here`linearlayout: layout_weight" solution ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define `android:wightsum="2"` then the sum of weight of all children components **must not be greater than 2**.

In your `xml` you have defined `weightsum` is `2` and sum of weight of both children is **50+50** which will definitely show you an error.

Change the weight of both button to **`1`**.

Your `xml` should look like,

```
<LinearLayout>
    <EditText>
    <LinearLayout android:weightsum="2">
        <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

.
.
.
```

Comment: the problem is that i am geting these attribure in the nested linearlayout
the only attribute avalible are android:layertype and android:layoutdirection no other attribute in the inner layout.

Comment: have you tried my answer? @IdreesAhmad I have said what changes you need to make and what causes an error.

Comment: yes i hav tried can you come on skype or any other?

Comment: No sorry but I can write your layout file as answer here.

Comment: my new code is as:
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText>

    <linearlayout
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal"
         >

        <Button
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </linearlayout>
    <TextView
</LinearLayout>

Comment: Here is your  answer. Open this doc https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Srig1g0q9-OWQi8PgSF0MyEIo-7uutvmdHdlKTsM9tk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: now when i go graphical layout:
Exception raised during rendering: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
The following classes could not be found:
- linearlayout (Change to LinearLayout, Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

Comment: @IdreesAhmad then `linearlayout` to `LinearLayout` it will work. And tell me when after you try it.

Answer (score 0):

There are some simple change to make both button equal.You are added weightSum = 2. Then you need to add layout_weight = "1" for both the button.

And  you need to set layout_width="0dp" for both the button. You can use value "match_parent" for the LinearLayout's layout_width attribute. Then it will take  50% or equal size  horizontally.  hope it will work fine.

Comment: the problem is that i am geting these attribure in the nested linearlayout the only attribute avalible are android:layertype and android:layoutdirection no other attribute in the inner layout

Comment: Did you make above suggested changes? inside of <LinearLayout> and child compounds.